# how to parse a HTML page with PHP5 and DOM?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

i'm working on some piece of code that should get the contents of a very specific html-tag of an html-document given.

```
$html = "<html>..........truncated.........<div>blablabla<br />xy</div>.....";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

echo $divs->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br>';
```

the html-code is just an example but shows the very problem i'm experiencing: i want to get the content of this DIV and i NEED the inner tags to be kept!
what nodeValue (as well as "textContent") does, is returning the contents of the correct node `with all inner tags stripped` (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

i'm out of ideas how to get this right atm... what i need is the equivalent to javascripts "innerHTML" or so... but i cant find such a method :(

how do i get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM is only good at parsing *well-formed* and 100% valid XML, so unless you're using 100% valid XHTML, it's going to fail.

What you want to use is the [**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library.

There are a great many tutorials on that site to help you w/ what you need.

Comment: DOM can parse real world HTML fine when you load it with `DOMDocument::loadHTML` or `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`. This will utilize libxml's HTML Parser module then.

Comment: In my experience, that's iffy at best. However, last time I tried was in 2009. Perhaps it's improved.

Answer (score 1):

This solution looks promising:

http://www.linked.com.mt/blog/code/php/php-domnode-tostring-xml/

```
$temp_doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$temp_node = $temp_doc->importNode($myDomNode, TRUE);
$temp_doc->appendChild($temp_node);
$my_node_as_string = $temp_doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen **[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)**? Might be too much for what you're trying to accomplish but it's worth taking a look at.